# hibernate fails to retrieve objects from DB

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm writing a project for college and I've encountered some strange phenomena.
The program supposed to serve a restaurant so it has a server side that manages all the needs of the different front ends. the different front ends are "dinner terminal", "kitchen terminal", "waiter terminal" and an "admin terminal".

When I add an object to the DB I see it in the DB and the kitchen terminal receives it and I see that the object it gets is the right one.

```
public void addSessionOrder(String id, SessionOrder sessionOrder)
{
Session context = clientSessions.get(id);

context.beginTransaction();
context.save(sessionOrder);
context.getTransaction()
        .commit();      
}
```

notice that each terminal (connection) has it's own session in hibernate.

however, once I try to update the status of a sessionorder i get this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at database.DatabaseContext.updateSessionOrderStatus(DatabaseContext.java:170)
at protocol.handlers.UpdateSessionOrderStatusHandler.handle(UpdateSessionOrderStatusHandler.java:35)
at server.ResturantServer.handleClientMessage(ResturantServer.java:126)
at server.ConnectionManager.handleClientMessage(ConnectionManager.java:86)
at server.SockJSSocketHandler$3.handle(SockJSSocketHandler.java:55)
```

this is the method:

```
public void updateSessionOrderStatus(String id, SessionOrder order, OrderStatus newStatus)
{
    Session context = clientSessions.get(id);

    context.beginTransaction();
    SessionOrder ord = (SessionOrder)context.get(SessionOrder.class, order.getOrderId());
    ord.setStatus(newStatus);
    context.update(ord);
    context.getTransaction()
            .commit();

}
```

The line that throws the exception is "ord.setStatus(newStatus);"
after debugging this is the info I have:
fields id and sessionOrder contain legit data and are initiated as needed.
sessionOrder.getOrderId() returns the needed ID for a corresponding object in the DB (it exists)
the query on the DB return null to ord.

Another thing I've noticed, if I turn the server off (kill hibernate) and restart everything, the whole things works fine. So I believe it has something to do with the fact that some session X inserted the object to the DB, and some other session Y tries to retrieve it afterwards.

the sessions are different and originate from different connections, and the specific order exists in the DB so I see no reason for it not to return the value.
I think it has something to do with caching of the model, however I'm quite a noob in hibernate so I can't pin point the problem.

Comment: Which line gives you the exception? Have you tried debugging to get more info?

Comment: I've edited the question to give more info

Comment: Try to enable [sql logging](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) in hibernate and see if you get more info from there. Just curious: what happens if you update the object you already have(`order`) instead of asking Hibernate for it again?

Comment: since the object I have is not a persisted version of the object trying to directly update is pointless I think. here is a log with SQL enabled http://pastebin.com/EfCTmn0s

Answer (score 0):

> sessionOrder.getOrderId() returns the needed ID for a corresponding object in the DB (it exists) the query on the DB return null to ord.

The ord object is null so it throws a NPE. I guess that hibernate cannot find the order with the given ID.

Add some logging here and you'll see what causes you trouble

Comment: well.. if the code fails at that line, that tells me that the ord object is null. There is no more NPE at that line

Comment: indeed, add some logging ;) it surely helps

Comment: this is a log that holds the event of the first click http://pastebin.com/2zh841xc. at line 1 the server receives a message to add a new order. at line 2 the servers informs the kitchen of the orders it needs to do. at line 3 the server receives a request for a persisted list of orders. at line 4 the server sends the persisted list of orders. at line 5 the server receives the first click from the kitchen to update the status of the order. at line 6 the bug is logged. at line 13 comes the second try to update the status which succeeds, however 2 click at the front end are needed.